# In poset category elements are objects while in group category elements are arrows

Tags: category-theory, soft-question

In a categorical poset, the elements of the poset are objects of the category, whereas in a categorical group, the elements are arrows.  why does such an apparent asymmetry  exist, and how can I understand it?

Thank you in advance for any insights into this possibly naive question.

Answer (score 3):

The elements of a group and the morphisms of a category are things you can compose. Two axioms of these compositions are the same – identity and associativity. The only differences are that for morphisms composition is partial because you can only compose morphisms with matching target and source, and that morphisms need not have an inverse. So if you restrict the category to one object and require the existence of inverses, you have all the ingredients of a group. You might want to take a look at [groupoids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Groupoid), which are in between: They have inverses like groups, but composition is partial as for morphisms.

In a poset, by contrast, what can be composed is not the elements but the relations between them. Transitivity is composition of relations with matching target and source, and reflexivity provides the identity for that composition.